# Return ranges of one column based on group number of a second column

Tags: awk, sed, range, multiple-columns

I have a file with two columns separated by a single tab or single space (either way is ok). The first column is sorted in ascending order. The second column can take three different numbers (0, 1 or 2). So taking the examples below:

```
col1 col2
15295557 2
15295594 2
15295834 2
15295937 1
15295959 1
15302817 1
15303844 0
15303848 0
15303851 0
15303860 0
15304062 0
15313455 2
15314748 2
15320909 2
15320945 2
```

---

What I would like is to group the first column in ranges based on the number in the second column. The desired output would be something like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
15295557 15295834 2
15295937 15302817 1
15303844 15304062 0
15313455 15320945 2
```

I believe awk or sed could do the trick easily, but my skills are really limited...
Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: What's the format of your input data? Is it comma or tab separated, or something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this awk:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} p2 != $2 {if (NR>1) print start, p1, p2; start = $1} {p1 = $1; p2 = $2} END{print start, p1, p2}' file

15295557    15295834    2
15295937    15302817    1
15303844    15304062    0
15313455    15320945    2
```

An expanded form:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
p2 != $2 {
   if (NR > 1)
      print start, p1, p2
   start = $1
}
{
   p1 = $1
   p2 = $2
}
END {
   print start, p1, p2
}' file
```